How to allow only numbers in certain input-field for Magento Admin Control-Table/Config-Table
I want to allow only numbers for a certain input field in a Magento Admin Control-Table/Config-Table. Has anyone done that before or has a hint?
Greez


I post the updated answer, kindly check that will work for you.

You have to added validation class.
$this->addColumn('yourfieldname', ['label' => __('Your Label'),'class' => 'required-entry validate-number']);


Hey,
unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. :/

I update the code, kindly check those things.

Dhiren thank you very much, this did it for me! But now i have the Problem with the required-enty Attribute. This field should not be required but if i undo this, it won't work.

you can remove this class : required-entry then run all magento commands again and then check.

Yup, I did and it worked! Thanks again! :)

If answer help, upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community.

In store configuration fields, you can use below code to allow numbers only
      <config>
        <sections>
            <newsletter translate="label" module="newsletter">
                <label>Custom Label</label>
                <tab>phone</tab>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>110</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <validate>validate-number</validate>
         </newsletter>
      </sections>
    </config>

